# Should student be a weak entity in DBMS?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I have this following database of a student portal project I am building. I'm new to databases but I know the concepts quite much. I wan't to ask that in my diagram should student be a weak entity as it depends on the department. If there is no department then there won't be any student to that department.

Apart from my main question I am a bit confused about the ATTENDANCE and GRADES Table. Have I related them correctly and are their attributes sufficient and correct ? I know I'm asking much but can you review my diagram and provide me suggestion to improve it even if it takes to make it from scratch.
Thanks.

[image: Student Portal Database Design]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Student doesn't need to be a weak entity set. While weak entity sets imply an existence dependency, existence dependencies don't imply weak entity sets. Total participation is possible for regular entity sets too.

Instead of looking at existence dependencies, look at identification. Weak entity sets can't be identified by their own attributes alone, they depend on a foreign key (usually in combination with a weak key) for identity. When an entity set has an independent identity like `Roll ID` (surrogate IDs are always independent), they're regular entities.

You seem to be confusing entity sets with tables, perhaps due to the mixed notation you're using. If I read your model correctly, `Grades` is a relationship between `Student` and `Courses` since it has a primary key that consists of two foreign keys. However, your diagram only links it to `Student` via an unnecessary `has` relationship.

You also have embedded relationships in your tables, e.g. `Courses` has a `Department` FK, but you didn't link the two in the diagram. `Enrolls` requires its own table, but you don't show one unlike for the other many-to-many relationships in your diagram.

`Attendance`, like `Grades`, represents a relationship between `Student` and `Courses`. You show an association with `Department` but don't indicate an FK. While in original ER notation we never indicate foreign keys as attributes, in your diagram this is inconsistent with most of the rest of your tables.

Edit:

Here's an example of how to represent `Grades` as a relationship between `Student` and `Courses`. I used original ER notation since I don't have a tool that implements your notation.

[image: Grades relationship between Student and Courses ER diagram]

Comment: Yes, I know I used a inconsistent notation for my sake only sorry about that and i also know that N:M requires another table which I will draw after I cleared my confusions. I would like to know that as you said which I agree that ATTENDANCE and GRADES should be along STUDENT and COURSE but I am failing to visualize it and how the diagram should be how can I rejust these. Where and to which I should connect by which realtion.

Comment: I added an example, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks alot it really helped! Was hoping to see that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Attendance table should be linked to Course and Student not Department as shown.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little that how can I put attendence between course and students when they are already link. I am failing to visualize ternary or n-ary relationship

Comment: If you think about it, students attend courses. In fact it would be better to have another table, Class where Course and Class have a one-to-many relationship. To pass a course for example, a student would have to attend a minimum x number of classes. Of course Course would have a many to one relationship with Department. So in a nutshell, Attendance --> Class --> Course --> Department